# read_csv 'NoneType' object has no attribute ''

Tags: pandas, ipython, export-to-csv, pandas-datareader

so I created a csv file with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Listing_Data1, columns = Field1)
df.to_csv('Listing_my.csv', sep=",", index = False)
```

Everything looks right in the csv file. However, when I read the csv file using the following code:

```
with open('Listing_my.csv',, 'r') as f: 
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
Field = next(reader)
Listing_Data = pd.read_csv('Listing_my.csv', usecols=Field)
```

When I tried to access to one of the attribute (i.e. Listing_Data.room_type). I got the following error message:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'room_type'

May I know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

ListingData has the value None.

You'll need to debug your code to figure out why pd.read_csv returned None, but it probably means it failed.